# Copy text and paste into a textarea using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

In a forum, I want to copy the original post and quote it and paste into a text area using jQuery:

[image]

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071520/jquery-copy-text-paste-into-textarea) post. However, it doesn't apply what I really need.

Comment: What code do you have so far? what have you attempted?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the original text in a `<div>` element like so:

```
<div id="original">
    Original text...
</div>
```

and the button like so:

```
<button id="copy">Copy Text</button>
```

and the `<textarea>` like so:

```
<textarea id="paste"></textarea>
```

You can simply use jQuery to get the value of the original and paste it into the `<textarea>` like so:

```
$("#copy").click(function() {
    $("#paste").val($("original").text());
});
```

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/2LfhLazq/).

Answer (score 1):

So, lets say you have the "original text" in a div with the ID `original`, the copy button has the ID `copy`, and the textarea has the ID `paste-here`. Then this simple snippet should to it:

```
//When the user clicks the copy button...
$('#copy').click(function() {
    //Take the text of the div...
    var text = $('#original').text();
    //...and put it in the div:
    $('#paste-here').val(text);
});
```

This will replace the content of the text area with the original text. If you just want to add it to the end, do this instead:

```
    //Take the text of the textarea, a linebreak, and the text of the div...
    var text = $('#paste-here').val() + '\n' + $('#original').text();
    //...and put it in the div:
    $('#paste-here').val(text);
```

Comment: On an off-topic note, I thought you were speaking Spanish with `tarea` and was wondering how that had anything to do with this before realizing it meant "textarea". Wow, I feel stupid.

Comment: lol I know no spanish. Naming an element just as the short form of the element type is horrible naming though, so I updated it to something a bit more instructive. :-)